# How to add extra include/lib path to Sublime (to compile pure C with gcc)

Tags: c, gcc, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I mananged to add sublime-build as follows:

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc -Wall ${file} -o ./bin/${file_base_name} -I${file_path}/lib && ./bin/${file_base_name}"],
"selector": "source.c",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"shell": true,


"variants": [
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["gcc -Wall ${file} -o ./bin/${file_base_name} -I${file_path}/lib && open ./bin/${file_base_name}"],
        "working_dir": "${file_path}",
        "shell": true

    }
 ]

}
```

But I failed to add extra include and libraries path to this "New Build System".  Please help me, many thanks!

If I test with simple C file, it is okay so other issues can be eliminated:

[image]

If I want to add extra "include", I get "fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory".

[image]

...even though I had added this extra "include" path to system environment path and the file in question has been there, as you can see from the pictures.

[image]

Comment: What does the actual command look like and what error message do you get?

Comment: Thanks, I had added the error message with pictures.

Comment: If you look at `shell_cmd` in the second screen shot there is no Include option. Why it isn't picked up I can't tell.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave up and switch to use Dev++ and CodeLite.